# SQLAlchemy - Relationship across four tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my setup:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'
    object_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.user_id'))

class ObjectHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object_histories'
    history_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Action(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'
    action_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class ActionDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'action_details'
    detail_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    history_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ObjectHistory.id')

    object = relationship('Object', secondary='object_histories',
                          primaryjoin='ActionDetail.history_id==ObjectHistory.history_id',
                          secondaryjoin='Object.object_id==ObjectHistory.object_id',
                          backref='action_details')

    user = relationship('User', ????, backref='action_details')
```

How can I create the `user` relationship on ActionDetail? Is it possible? I've tried something similar to the `object` relationship above it, but to no avail.